# Kotlin X Jetpack Compose - Project with GPS(coordinates) and SMS/CALL feature

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I've been stuck in this problem for 2days. It always throw **"@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function"** I wanted to use device default sms feature where in my logic it will retrieve the phone number from firestore, then if the user click the icon of location it will retrieve the location then using the phone number as a recipient. In my Icon section it will only simply retrieve the loc and number then call the sendLocationSMS()

This is my code structure

SmsUtils.kt File

```
object SmsUtils {
    fun sendSMS(context: Context, phoneNumber: String, message: String) {
        val smsIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto:$phoneNumber"))
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", message)
        context.startActivity(smsIntent)
    }

    fun openSmsApp(context: Context) {
        val smsIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        smsIntent.type = "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"
        context.startActivity(smsIntent)
    }
}
```

MedicPage.kt

```
@Composable
private fun sendLocationSMS(location: Location, phoneNumber: String) {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val smsMessage = "Help! I'm at Latitude: ${location.latitude}, Longitude: ${location.longitude}"
    SmsUtils.sendSMS(context, phoneNumber, smsMessage)

    // Optionally, you can also open the SMS app with the pre-populated message
    SmsUtils.openSmsApp(context)
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun medicPage(navController: NavController?, selectedMunicipality: String?) {
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed)
    val isPreview = LocalInspectionMode.current
    val containerColor = Color(0xFFFFD317)
    var selectedMunicipality by remember { mutableStateOf<Municipality?>(null) }

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val municipalities = remember { mutableStateOf(listOf<Municipality>()) }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("municipality_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val defaultMunicipalityName = sharedPreferences.getString("selected_municipality", "Valencia")
    val finalMunicipalityForm = defaultMunicipalityName

    var errorState by remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }
    // Call getEmergencyPhoneNumber within a composable function
    val emergencyPhoneNumber = remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }

   // var selectedMedic by remember { mutableStateOf<Medic?>(null) }

    Log.d("MedicPage", "Selected Municipality: $finalMunicipalityForm")

    // State variable to hold the contact number
    var contactNumber1 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var contactNumber2 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var contactNumber3 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    var selectedPhoneNumber by remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }
    val dialerLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) { result ->
        // Handle the result if needed
    }

    // Create an instance of LocationHelper within the composable function
    val locationHelper = LocationHelper(context = LocalContext.current)
    // State variable to hold the user's location
    var userLocation by remember { mutableStateOf<Location?>(null) }

    // Call getDeviceLocation within a composable function
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        locationHelper.getDeviceLocation { location ->
            userLocation = location
            Log.d("Location_ShareMedicPage", "Latitude: ${location.latitude}, Longitude: ${location.longitude}")

        }
    }

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        // Clean up when the composable is disposed
        onDispose {
            locationHelper.stopLocationUpdates()
        }
    }

    // Query contact document
    val db = Firebase.firestore
    db.collection("Emergency Contacts")
        .document("$finalMunicipalityForm")
        .collection("Medics")
        .document("medicDC_1")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { medicSnapshot ->
            val retrievedContactNumber = medicSnapshot.getString("contactnumMD1")

            if (retrievedContactNumber != null) {
                // Update the state variable
                contactNumber1 = retrievedContactNumber
                Log.e("EmergencyContactScreen", "Number Retrieved $contactNumber1")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            // Handle the error, you might want to log or show an error message
            Log.e("EmergencyContactScreen", "Error getting contact number", exception)
        }

    db.collection("Emergency Contacts")
        .document("$finalMunicipalityForm")
        .collection("Medics")
        .document("medicDC_2")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { medicSnapshot ->
            val retrievedContactNumber = medicSnapshot.getString("contactnumMD2")

            if (retrievedContactNumber != null) {
                // Update the state variable
                contactNumber2 = retrievedContactNumber
                Log.e("EmergencyContactScreen", "Number Retrieved $contactNumber2")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            // Handle the error, you might want to log or show an error message
            Log.e("EmergencyContactScreen", "Error getting contact number", exception)
        }

    db.collection("Emergency Contacts")
        .document("$finalMunicipalityForm")
        .collection("Medics")
        .document("medicDC_3")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { medicSnapshot ->
            val retrievedContactNumber = medicSnapshot.getString("contactnumMD3")

            if (retrievedContactNumber != null) {
                // Update the state variable
                contactNumber3 = retrievedContactNumber
                Log.e("EmergencyContactScreen", "Number Retrieved $contactNumber3")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            // Handle the error, you might want to log or show an error message
            Log.e("EmergencyContactScreen", "Error getting contact number", exception)
        }





    ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            DrawerComponent(drawerState) { municipality ->
                selectedMunicipality = municipality
                Log.d("LOCATION", "HomeScreen: $municipality")
            }
        }
    ) {
    Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color(0xFF1E2128))
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
            ) {
                HeaderComponentUser(drawerState)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

                if (isPreview) {
                    // Placeholder for the map in preview mode
                    Box(
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .background(Color(0xFFFFFFFF))
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(200.dp)
                    ) {
                        Text("Map Placeholder", textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
                    }
                } else {
                    // Actual map component when not in preview
                    selectedMunicipality?.let { municipality ->
                        MapComponent(
                            modifier = Modifier.weight(0.5f),
                            municipality = municipality
                        )
                    }
                }



                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))

                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(16.dp), // Add padding as needed
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "MEDIC EMERGENCY CONTACTS",
                        color = Color.White,
                        style = LocalTextStyle.current,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                        // Adjust the horizontal padding as needed
                    )
                }


                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))

                // UI ELEMENTS
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(containerColor) // Set the background color as needed
                ) {

                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(16.dp)
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Rescuer 1", // To be replaced in Logical Side
                            color = Color.Black,
                            style = LocalTextStyle.current,
                            modifier = Modifier.paddingFromBaseline(
                                10.dp,
                                0.dp
                            ) // Adjust vertical spacing as needed
                        )

                            Row(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .height(50.dp)
                                    .padding(5.dp),
                                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                            ) {
                                Box(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .size(width = 150.dp, height = 40.dp)
                                        .border(2.dp, Color.Black)
                                        .background(Color.White),
                                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                                ) {
                                    Text(
                                        text = "$contactNumber1",
                                        color = Color.Black,
                                        style = LocalTextStyle.current
                                    )
                                }

                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(2.dp)) // Adjust the spacing between icons


                                // Inside medicPage composable
                                Icon(
                                    imageVector = Icons.Default.LocationOn,
                                    contentDescription = null,
                                    tint = Color.Black,
                                    modifier = Modifier.size(115.dp).clickable {
                                        userLocation?.let { location ->
                                            selectedPhoneNumber?.let { phoneNumber ->
                                                // Call a function to handle sending SMS with location and phone number
                                                sendLocationSMS(
                                                    location = location,
                                                    phoneNumber = phoneNumber
                                                )
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                )


                                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(2.dp)) // Adjust the spacing between icons

                                Icon(
                                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Phone,
                                    contentDescription = null,
                                    tint = Color.Black,
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .size(115.dp)
                                        .clickable {
                                            selectedPhoneNumber = contactNumber1
                                            // You can also launch the dialer here
                                            selectedPhoneNumber?.let { phoneNumber ->
                                                val dialIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:$phoneNumber"))
                                                dialerLauncher.launch(dialIntent)
                                            }
                                        }
                                )
                        }

                    }

         



@Preview
@Composable
fun medicPagePreview() {
    EMContactsTheme {
        // Replace null with the selected municipality for preview

        medicPage(navController = null, selectedMunicipality = null)
    }
}
```

```
**THIS IS THE ONE THAT KEPT THROWING ERROR** 
  Icon(
                                    imageVector = Icons.Default.LocationOn,
                                    contentDescription = null,
                                    tint = Color.Black,
                                    modifier = Modifier.size(115.dp).clickable {
                                        userLocation?.let { location ->
                                            selectedPhoneNumber?.let { phoneNumber ->
                                                // Call a function to handle sending SMS with location and phone number
                                                **sendLocationSMS(
                                                    location = location,
                                                    phoneNumber = phoneNumber
                                                )**
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                )
```

I have revise the codes many times but i kept getting this error

I am expecting to be able to use the device sms feature with pre-populated message with the location and number as recieptent

Comment: It is because You are calling @Composable function from the Non Composable Scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your function below

```
private fun sendLocationSMS(context : Context, location: Location, phoneNumber: String) {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val smsMessage = "Help! I'm at Latitude: ${location.latitude}, Longitude: ${location.longitude}"
    SmsUtils.sendSMS(context, phoneNumber, smsMessage)

    // Optionally, you can also open the SMS app with the pre-populated message
    SmsUtils.openSmsApp(context)
}
```

And Write MainScreen As Below. We have passed the context from the @Compsale to the other scope and it will work as you want. And this is the good practice

```
@Composable
fun medicPage(navController: NavController?, selectedMunicipality: String?) {
    ....
    // Inside medicPage composable
 
    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Default.LocationOn,
        contentDescription = null,
        tint = Color.Black,
        modifier = Modifier.size(115.dp).clickable {
            userLocation?.let { location ->
                selectedPhoneNumber?.let { phoneNumber ->
                    // Call a function to handle sending SMS with location and phone number
                    sendLocationSMS(
                        context = context,
                        location = location,
                        phoneNumber = phoneNumber
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )
        ....
}
```

Comment: however i do have other context sir which is for the sharing of municipality

Comment: You can keep that I have just shown you. just add the required change in your code. check out updated code

Comment: I have revise the code with your given code sir, but 2 new "Functions which invoke "@Composable functions must be marked with the @Composable annotation" error pop up which is in "private fun sendLocationSMS" and in   "val context = LocalContext.current"
which is still in the sendLocationSMS fun sir

Comment: Oh no never mind sir thank you very much i have finally remove this flag thanks !